# OpenJPA QueryCache caching non cacheable entities

Tags: jpa, caching, openjpa

I'm using **glassfish 3.2.2** with **OpenJPA 2.2.1**

In my persistence.xml I have:

```
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
<properties>
        <property name="openjpa.QueryCache" value="true(CacheSize=10000, SoftReferenceSize=1000)"/>
        <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="true(CacheSize=20000, SoftReferenceSize=1000)"/>
        <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported"/>
</properties>
```

I only want entites that have the `@Cacheable` annotation to be cached.

However after running a named query on an entity that does not have the `@Cacheable` annotation if I then run that named query again, it will return the results from the query cache.

If I do a direct find against the entity it does not get the entity from the data cache.

So why does `@Cacheable` prevent an entity from being put in the data cache, but does not prevent it from being put in the query cache?

Is there a way to prevent all entities that do not have the `@Cacheable` annotation from being put in the query cache?

**Pseudo code**

**Entity class:**

```
@NamedQueries ({ @NamedQuery(name="MyEntity.getByName", query="select e from MyEntity e where e.name = :name")})

@Entity
public class MyEntity
{
  @Id
  @Column
  private long id;

  @Column
  private String name;
}
```

**EJB:**

```
@Stateless
public class MyEJB
{
  @PersistenceContext
  EntityManager em;

  public MyEntity getEntityByName(String name) {
    TypedQuery<MyEntity> namedQuery = em.createNamedQuery("MyEntity.getByName", MyEntity.class);
    namedQuery.setParameter("name", name); 
    return namedQuery.getSingleResult(); 
  }
}
```

Upon further investigation:

This problem might be hard to discover, since as long as your query returns the same ids, you will get the same results regardless of whether or not it is in the query cache.

For instance if I just update the data of the row returned in the database, then it will bring back the new data.

In my case the batch process is deleting the row, and then reinserting a new row with a new id.  So the query cache is storing the original id of the row, so that when I run the query, it now returns null, since that id no longer exists.  If I clear the query cache, then it correctly brings back the new row.

So it would be nice if entities that do not have the `@Cacheable` annotation never make it into the query cache in the first place.

Comment: How are you determining that the results are coming from the QueryCache?

Comment: I change the database outside of the entity manager, and it still brings back the stale data. However if I do a direct em.find it brings back the new data.  I also looked at the query cache directly using org.apache.openjpa.persistence.OpenJPAPersistence.cast(em.getEntityManagerFactory()).getQueryResultCache() and inspected the object using IntelliJ and found the query and the entity inside of the cache.

Comment: Please, write pseudo code to better explain the scenario that you are running.

Comment: The result from the EJB method in the pseudo code is used on a JSF page.  However there is also a batch process that updates the database outside of the entity manager.  So for the entities that are never updated outside of the entity manager I would like those to use the query cache, and those entities I have annotated with @Cacheable. And then since I specified ENABLE_SELECTIVE for the shared cache, I want all other entities to not use the data cache or the query cache.

Comment: What version of OpenJPA, this *should* work as you want.

Comment: The version of OpenJPA is 2.2.1, which I believe is the latest release version.

Comment: When you execute your updated outside of the EntityManager, are you updating the name field?

Comment: No, it doesn't update the fields I'm querying on.

Comment: I think the more interesting question is why is it being put into the query cache in the first place?

Comment: I'd suggest posting some sort of a unit test to the OpenJPA mailing lists.